# Pass data to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, attributes

I have a jsp page with a few fields. I need to use some of these fields  in a servlet to get the details of a Car. This is the form in the jsp page:

```
<form method="post" action="Update">  
                <table id="centerTable" width="600">
                   <tr>                              
                       <th><h5>Car ID</h5></th>
                       <th><h5>Car Brand</h5></th>
                    </tr>                           
                    <tr>
                        <td>${bookedCar.id}</td>
                        <td>${bookedCar.carbrand}</td>
                    </tr>                 
                </table>

                </br></br>                                    
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Cancel Booking"></p>

 </form>
```

In the servlet Update.java, I have the following in the doPost. I require the car id to use in the Update servlet but I keep getting the value as null. Am I calling the attribute incorrectly?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    Cars myCar = (Cars)request.getAttribute("bookedCar");
    String carID = (String)request.getAttribute("bookedCar.id");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to send the information in the form submit, so you need to use a input tag to send this information so change the table in this way:

```
<form method="post" action="Update">  
    <table id="centerTable" width="600">
        <tr>                              
            <th><h5>Car ID</h5></th>
            <th><h5>Car Brand</h5></th>
        </tr>                           
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="bookedCarId" value="${bookedCar.id}" readonly/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bookedCar" value="${bookedCar.carbrand}"  readonly/></td>
       </tr>                 
     </table>
     </br></br>                                    
     <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Cancel Booking"></p>
</form>
```

To get the values send in the form submit you need to use the name attribute of the input tags but using the getParameter function from the HttpServletRequest object, so:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    String myCar = request.getParameter("bookedCar");
    String carID = request.getParameter("bookedCarId");
}
```

As you see this method get the string parameters send in the request, with this info you can get the car object, or you can store this object as attribute of the session object so in the next request you can get this object.